# JQuery Ajax Performance (JSON)

Tags: jquery, json

i have a page made AJAX/HTTP Request and the result is JSON formatted .
using JQuery GET :

```
$.get('..',{..},function(data){
   console.log('Hey Iam finish !');
},'JSON')
```

The problem is `console.log('Hey Iam finish !');` executed after many seconds (3>) as Firebug says .

Server : WINDOWS IIS ( Unfortunately ) , PHP .

Server Code : 
i try to remove JSON and just echo :
`echo "HI";` 
the result is same .

**UPDATE**

Summary : Firebug says the AJAX request finish but result appear only after 3> seconds

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. Do you feel that the AJAX request is taking too long?

Comment: What is the question?  If you are curious of the length of time the AJAX call takes to return.  I suggest you evaluate the page you are trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in FireBug 1.8.4( FireFox 5/Linux Mint) it not give the accurate response time , i try firebug lite on chrome , and it give the accurate one .

Answer (score 2):

Your serverside code is taking a long time to process, you should check to see if there is any time to gain in optimizing there. Your Javascript/jQuery is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I found problems with the JSON parsing causing script timeouts in IE. Using eval rather then JSON.parse was quicker. But only any good if you absolutely trust the source of the JSON i.e. it's from you. Even then it might not be a risk worth taking